# DHL API Tracking Integration C#

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, api, e-commerce

I need to implement tracking numbers via API, currently have problems with implementing that. First, when I try to track order online with tracking number 92748999917742000013539990 here http://webtrack.dhlglobalmail.com/?trackingnumber=92748999917742000013539990, it tracks sucessfully, but when I try to track it here: http://www.dhl.com/en/express/tracking.html, it  says: (Not found): No result found for your DHL query. Please try again.

I try to send XML API call to address: http://xmlpitest-ea.dhl.com/XMLShippingServlet, and when I send tracking number from DHL example 8564385550, it returns correct response with tracking details, but when I try to to send my tracking number 92748999917742000013539990 or any other like this, it returns error XML:

```
Error Parsing incoming request XML Error: Datatype error: In element
AWBNumber Value 92748999917742000013539990 with length 26 exceeds maximum length facet of                    11.. at line 17, column 52
```

Can someone clarify?
Appreciate any help.

Comment: You are using the wrong API: http://api.dhlglobalmail.com/docs/v1/

Comment: thank you! please write this as an answer, I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong API in your project.

`xmlpitest-ea.dhl.com` is the test endpoint for the DHL express API, but you seem to need to use the new DHL eCommerce API, which documentation is found here:  [api.dhlglobalmail.com/docs/v1](http://api.dhlglobalmail.com/docs/v1)